# ¿De donde sale el codigo del metodo config('auth.default.domain') en LARAVEL?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

tengo una duda ya que he instalado laravel 5.4 y el template adminLTE 3.0, en el cual luego de estar todo funcionando lo puse en español, todo normal hasta ahi, luego quice cambiar el codigo html del login, pero me encuentro con que el codigo es generado por una funcion dentro de la vista de login.blade.php

el path del archivo es: resoruces/views/vendor/adminlte/auth/login.blade.php

```
  @extends('adminlte::layouts.auth')
  @section('htmlheader_title')
   Log in
  @endsection
 @section('content')
 <body class="hold-transition login-page">
 <div id="app" v-cloak>
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <a href="{{ url('/home') }}"><b><span style="font-size: 50px">Admin</span></b>LTE</a>
        </div><!-- /.login-logo -->

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> {{ trans('adminlte_lang::message.someproblems') }}<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
      <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg"> {{ trans('adminlte_lang::message.siginsession') }} </p>

    <login-form name="{{ config('auth.providers.users.field','email') }}"
                domain="{{ config('auth.defaults.domain','') }}"></login-form>

    @include('adminlte::auth.partials.social_login')

    <a href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">{{ trans('adminlte_lang::message.forgotpassword') }}</a><br>
    <a href="{{ url('/register') }}" class="text-center">{{ trans('adminlte_lang::message.registermember') }}</a>

</div>

</div>
</div>
@include('adminlte::layouts.partials.scripts_auth')

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
            increaseArea: '20%' // optional
        });
    });
</script>
 </body>
@endsection
```

En donde este pedazo de codigo genera el formulario y deseo cambiar los estilos con las clases de los div pero no se de donde sale deseo saber como cambiar las clases o de donde sale para poder editarlas:

```
       <login-form name="{{ config('auth.providers.users.field','email') }}"
                domain="{{ config('auth.defaults.domain','') }}"></login-form>
```

Lo que deseo saber es como puedo editar las clases de los div generados o de donde salen los div generados con esa funcion para editarlos.

Comment: Disculpa, no viene al caso pero ¿donde descargaste adminlte 3.0?

Comment: Lo descargue con composer usando  e comando
`composer require "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel:3.*"`

Comment: q diferencia tiene con el 2? O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El helper [config()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-config) va a buscar dentro del directorio app/config lo que especifiques como primer parámetro, la notación de . implica que el primer parámetro es el nombre del archivo, y a continuación los valores dentro del array de dicho archivo.

En otras palabras, `config('auth.defaults.domain','')` va a buscar dentro del archivo `app/config/auth.php` el valor de `domain` dentro del array `defaults`, y en caso que no encuentre dicho valor, utilizará un valor vacío por defecto `''`.

---

Si deseas cambiar el contenido de `<login form name="..." domain="..."></login-form>`, lo encuentras en `resources/assets/js/components/auth/LoginForm.vue`, es un template de vue.js

```
<template>
 <form method="post" @submit.prevent="submit" @keydown="clearErrors($event.target.name)">
  <div class="alert alert-success text-center" v-show="form.succeeded" id="result"> {{ trans('adminlte_lang_message.loggedin') }} <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> {{ trans('adminlte_lang_message.entering') }}</div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback" :class="{ 'has-error': form.errors.has('email') }" v-if="type === 'email'">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="name" value="" v-model="form.email" @change="adddomain" autofocus/>
   <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" :class="[icon]"></span>
   <transition name="fade">
    <span class="help-block" v-if="form.errors.has('email')" v-text="form.errors.get('email')" id="validation_error_email"></span>
   </transition>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group has-feedback" :class="{ 'has-error': form.errors.has('username') }" v-else>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="name" v-model="form.username" @change="adddomain" autofocus/>
   <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" :class="[icon]"></span>
   <transition name="fade">
    <span class="help-block" v-if="form.errors.has('username')" v-text="form.errors.get('username')" id="validation_error_username"></span>
   </transition>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group has-feedback" :class="{ 'has-error': form.errors.has('password') }">
   <input type="password" class="form-control" :placeholder="trans('adminlte_lang_message.password')" name="password" v-model="form.password"/>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
   <transition name="fade">
    <span class="help-block" v-if="form.errors.has('password')" v-text="form.errors.get('password')" id="validation_error_password"></span>
   </transition>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="checkbox icheck">
     <label>
      <input style="display:none;" type="checkbox" name="remember" v-model="form.remember"> {{ trans('adminlte_lang_message.remember') }}
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" v-text="trans('adminlte_lang_message.buttonsign')" :disabled="form.errors.any()"><i v-if="form.submitting" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</template>
```

https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/auth/LoginForm.vue

Comment: Muchas gracias por tua porte y si tienes razon en esa ruta yo tambien imagine que podria encontrar eso por la parte de los arreglos en la carpeta config/auth.php pero el template de vue.js, lo modifique y este no se actuliza en la vista lo cual quiere decir que no esta siendo usado en la vista, lo probe insertando codigo html como un mensaje dentro de <h1>Hola</h1> pero no muestra nada, todavia sigo buscando pero no encuentro de donde se genera ese codigo. 
Muchas gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Claro que sí es ese, revisa el código donde se registra el componente: `Vue.component('login-form', require('./components/auth/LoginForm.vue'))` https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js#L60 , probablemente no ves los cambios porque no estás recompilando los assets.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo si era la falta de compilar los assets, aunque tuve ciertos problemas de errores que salen al compilar con nmp, pero ya logre editar lo que deseaba Muchas gracias